# Css with laravel project dont work ( layout usage )

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have a laravel project with this organisation for my view:

```
 view/
    ----- layout/
    ----- ----- index.blade.php ( the main file where i call, another by extend )
    ----- service/
    ----- ----- index.blade.php (service page )
    ----- about_us/
    ----- ----- index.blade.php ( about page ) 
    ----- home/
    ----- ----- welcome.blade.php (my home page )
```

my route file :

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home/welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/a_propos', function () {
        return view('a_propos/index');  
    })->name('a_propos');

    Route::get('/team', function () {
        return view('team/index');
    })->name('team');

    Route::get('/avis_clients', function () {
        return view('avis_clients/index');
    })->name('avis_clients');

    Route::get('/nos_services', function () {
        return view('nos_services/index');
    })->name('services');

    Route::get('/blog', function () {
        return view('blog/index');
    })->name('blog');

    Route::get('/article', function () {
        return view('blog/show');
    })->name('article');

    Route::get('/contacts', function () {
        return view('contacts/index');
    })->name('contacts');

    Route::get('/faq', function () {
        return view('faq/index');
    })->name('faq');
```

my service page look like :

```html
@extends("layouts/index")



@section("content")

<!-- Start breadcumb Area -->

<div class="page-area">

            <div class="breadcumb-overlay"></div>

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                  .......
                     JUST MORE OF HTML
                  .......

        </div>

       </div>

      </div>

                    </div>

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>

  <!-- End Service area -->

@endsection
```

```html
this is the content of my main layout file
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

 

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>HR CONSULTING & CO</title>

  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!-- favicon -->  

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/logo/favicon.ico">



  <!-- all css here -->



  <!-- bootstrap v3.3.6 css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

  <!-- owl.carousel css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.carousel.css') }}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.transitions.css') }}">

        <!-- meanmenu css -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/meanmenu.min.css') }}">

  <!-- font-awesome css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/icon.css') }}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/flaticon.css') }}">

  <!-- magnific css -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/magnific.css') }}">

  <!-- venobox css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/venobox.css') }}">

  <!-- style css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

  <!-- responsive css -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/responsive.css') }}">



  <!-- modernizr css -->

  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

 </head>

  <body>



  <!--[if lt IE 8]>

   <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>

  <![endif]-->



        <div id="preloader"></div>

        <header>

            <!-- Start top bar -->

            <div class="topbar-area fix hidden-xs">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class=" col-md-8 col-sm-8">

                            <div class="topbar-left">

                                <ul>

                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> House-4,2/3 avenew,Dubai</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> info@nigocio.com</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+0133 6454 432</a></li>

                                </ul>  

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">

                            <div class="topbar-right">

                                <div class="top-social">

         <ul>

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

         </ul> 

        </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- End top bar -->

            <!-- header-area start -->

            <div id="sticker" class="header-area hidden-xs">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- logo start -->

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">

                            <div class="logo">

                                <!-- Brand -->

                                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll sticky-logo" href="index-2.html">

                                    <img src="img/logo/logo.png" alt="">

                                </a>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- logo end -->

                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">

                            <div class="header-right-link">

                                <!-- search option start -->

                                <form action="#">

                                    <div class="search-option">

                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">

                                        <button class="button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

                                    </div>

                                    <a class="main-search" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>

                                </form>

                                <!-- search option end -->

                            </div>

                            <!-- mainmenu start -->

                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-example">

                                    <div class="main-menu">

                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                            <li><a class="pagess" href="index-2.html">Home</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

             <li><a href="index-2.html">Home 01</a></li>

             <li><a href="index-3.html">Home 02</a></li>

             <li><a href="index-4.html">Home 03</a></li>

            </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a class="pagess" href="#">About us</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

             <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>

             <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>

             <li><a href="review.html">Review</a></li>

             <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>

             <li><a href="error.html">Error</a></li>

            </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a class="pagess" href="#">Services</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

             <li><a href="services.html">Services 01</a></li>

             <li><a href="services-2.html">Services 02</a></li>

             <li><a href="single-service.html">Services Details</a></li>

            </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a class="pagess" href="#">Projects</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

             <li><a href="project-2.html">Project 2 Column</a></li>

             <li><a href="project-3.html">Project 3 Column</a></li>

             <li><a href="project-4.html">Project 4 Column</a></li>

             <li><a href="single-project.html">Project Details</a></li>

            </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a class="pagess" href="#">Blog</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

             <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>

             <li><a href="blog-sidebar.html">Blog Sidebar</a></li>

             <li><a href="blog-details.html">Blog Details</a></li>

            </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a href="contact.html">contacts</a></li>

                                        </ul>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </nav>

                            <!-- mainmenu end -->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- header-area end -->

            <!-- mobile-menu-area start -->

            <div class="mobile-menu-area hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="mobile-menu">

                                <div class="logo">

                                    <a href="index-2.html"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" alt="" /></a>

                                </div>

                                <nav id="dropdown">

                                    <ul>

                                        <li><a class="pagess" href="index-2.html">Home</a>

           <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="index-2.html">Home 01</a></li>

            <li><a href="index-3.html">Home 02</a></li>

            <li><a href="index-4.html">Home 03</a></li>

           </ul>

          </li>

          <li><a class="pagess" href="#">About us</a>

           <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="{{ route('a_propos') }}">A propos</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('team') }}">Equipe</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('avis_clients') }}">Avis clients</a></li>

            <li><a href="{{ route('faq') }}">FAQ</a></li>

            <li><a href="error.html">Error</a></li>

           </ul>

          </li>

          <li><a class="pagess" href="{{ route('services') }}">Services</a>

           <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="services.html">Services 01</a></li>

            <li><a href="services-2.html">Services 02</a></li>

            <li><a href="single-service.html">Services Details</a></li>

           </ul>

          </li>

          <li><a class="pagess" href="#">Projects</a>

           <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="project-2.html">Project 2 Column</a></li>

            <li><a href="project-3.html">Project 3 Column</a></li>

            <li><a href="project-4.html">Project 4 Column</a></li>

            <li><a href="single-project.html">Project Details</a></li>

           </ul>

          </li>

          <li><a class="pagess" href="{{ route('blog') }}">Blog</a>

           <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>

            <li><a href="blog-sidebar.html">Blog Sidebar</a></li>

            <li><a href="blog-details.html">Blog Details</a></li>

           </ul>

          </li>

          <li><a href="contact.html">contacts</a></li>

                                    </ul>

                                </nav>

                            </div>     

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- mobile-menu-area end -->  

        </header>

        <!-- header end -->





        @yield('content')





        <!-- Start Footer bottom Area -->

        <footer>

            <div class="footer-area">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="footer-content">

                                <div class="footer-head">

                                    <h4>information</h4>

                                    <p>

                                        You can contact us our consectetur adipisicing elit.

                                    </p>

                                    <div class="footer-contacts">

                                        <p><span>Tel:</span> +0133 6454 432</p>

                                        <p><span>Email:</span>info@nigocio.com</p>

                                        <p><span>Location:</span>House-4,2/3 avenew,Dubai</p>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="footer-icons">

                                        <ul>

                                            <li>

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>

                                                </a>

                                            </li>

                                            <li>

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>

                                                </a>

                                            </li>

                                            <li>

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>

                                                </a>

                                            </li>

                                            <li>

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>

                                                </a>

                                            </li>

                                            <li>

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>

                                                </a>

                                            </li>

                                        </ul>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- end single footer -->

                        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm col-xs-12">

                            <div class="footer-content">

                                <div class="footer-head">

                                    <h4>Services Link</h4>

                                    <ul class="footer-list">

                                        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Factory </a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">ICT Manegment</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Energy</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Environment</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Bank</a></li>

                                    </ul>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- end single footer -->

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="footer-content">

                                <div class="footer-head">

                                    <h4>Recent Post</h4>

                                    <div class="single-blog">

                                        <div class="blog-content">

                                           <div class="blog-title">

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <h4>Business manegment</h4>

                                                </a>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="blog-text">

                                                <p>Redug Lagre dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit..</p>

                                                <a class="blog-btn" href="#">Read more</a>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="single-blog">

                                        <div class="blog-content">

                                           <div class="blog-title">

                                                <a href="#">

                                                    <h4>Business consultant services</h4>

                                                </a>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="blog-text">

                                                <p>Redug Lagre dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit..</p>

                                                <a class="blog-btn" href="#">Read more</a>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- end single footer -->

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="footer-content last-content">

                                <div class="footer-head">

                                    <h4>Subscribe</h4>

                                    <p>

                                        Are you looking for professional advice for your new business.Are you looking for professional advice for your new business

                                    </p>

                                    <div class="subs-feilds">

                                        <div class="suscribe-input">

                                            <input type="email" class="email form-control width-80" id="sus_email" placeholder="Type Email">

                                            <button type="submit" id="sus_submit" class="add-btn">Subscribe</button>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- end single footer -->

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="footer-area-bottom">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="copyright">

                                <p>

                                    Copyright © 2018

                                    <a href="#">Nigocio</a> All Rights Reserved

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </footer>

  

  <!-- all js here -->



  <!-- jquery latest version -->

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap js -->

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- owl.carousel js -->

  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Counter js -->

  <script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

  <!-- waypoint js -->

  <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>

  <!-- isotope js -->

        <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

        <!-- stellar js -->

        <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

  <!-- magnific js -->

        <script src="js/magnific.min.js"></script>

  <!-- venobox js -->

  <script src="js/venobox.min.js"></script>

        <!-- meanmenu js -->

        <script src="js/jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>

  <!-- Form validator js -->

  <script src="js/form-validator.min.js"></script>

  <!-- plugins js -->

  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

  <!-- main js -->

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

 </body>



</html>
```

My probem is that, for my first page my css correctly work, but when i try to acces to another page, my css dosent work ( i mean that i have just the html in output in my navigator ) !

I call my css files by `asset("css/style.css")` method in `layout/index.blade.php` file ! and this file is called for all pages , so normaly css may work with all pages

How i can fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by, “It doesn’t work”?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell why "it dosent work" if you don't post the relevant files; namely the views.

Comment: sorry , i will add it ! the “It doesn’t work” mean that in my navigator i get just the html , without css ! i dont know if i explain right

Comment: Did you imported the css file in the rest of the files? Maybe for the file that the CSS works you imported a template?

Comment: i have import css in my main layout file , and this file i used in all page of my website

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you take the default welcome file generated by laravel, check in your other files if you write the correct `@extends('layout.index')` and not `@extend('layout.index')` at the beginning

Comment: thanks for this mark , its just there that i have make this mistake , in my code its right !

Comment: dont forget the main layout

Comment: Is layout o layouts your folder name?

Comment: it is layouts !

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem , 
its in the way that i have make my extends its not "/" but "." in the links !

@extends("a_propos.index")